# Magento2 - Pagination getPagerHtml() returns empty

Tags: magento2, pagination

I am trying to get pagination on my collection in block when i call from PHTML file it returns nothing, not showing pagination but $pageSize is working fine.
This function getPagerHtml() in phtml is not working

here is my function

```
  public function getTransactionsArchive(){
        //get values of current page
        $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    //get values of current limit
        $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 10;


        $customer_id = $this->request->getParam('id');
        $filters = array("customer_id" => $customer_id,"status" => 2,"cm_transaction_date" => array('to' => date("Y-m-01 00:00:00")));


        $transactionFactory = $this->_transactionFactory->create();
        $Collection = $transactionFactory->getCollection();
        foreach($filters as $filter => $value){
            $Collection->addFieldToFilter($filter, $value);
        }
        $Collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $Collection->setCurPage($page);

        return $Collection;
    }
```

and here is my layout function

```
  protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getTransactionsArchive()) {
            // create pager block for collection
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','my.custom.pager');
             // assign collection to pager
            $pager->setLimit(10)->setCollection($this->getTransactionsArchive());
            $pager->setAvailableLimit([10=>10,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100]);
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);// set pager block in layout
        }
        return $this;
}
```

and this is my pagerhtml

```
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}
```

and in my phtml calling this as

```
<?php if ($this->getPagerHtml()):
<div class="toolbar bottom"><?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?  I m also facing that issue @Asad Ullah

Comment: To be honest its a long time back i forgot how i resolved it sorry man @divyasekar

Answer (score 0):

> Add `$this->getTransactionsArchive()` in `_prepareLayout()`

```
  protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getTransactionsArchive()) {
            // create pager block for collection
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','my.custom.pager');
             // assign collection to pager
            $pager->setLimit(10)->setCollection($this->getTransactionsArchive());
            $pager->setAvailableLimit([10=>10,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100]);
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);// set pager block in layout
            $this->getTransactionsArchive()->load(); //Add This
        }
        return $this;
}
```

Comment: tried this nothing.....still the same

Comment: do you any other solution?